# read ASCII code file using fscanf

Tags: c, ascii, scanf

I am trying to read an ASCII text file and write it into binary file. The text file is unlimited in size. First, I tried to read the text file before writing it. However, I keep getting segmentation fault. I don't understand what may cause the problem. Even using gdb, I still cannot figure out the problem. Please advise.

### Code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

typedef struct _FileData
{
int a;
double b;
char dataStr[56];
}FileData;


int main()
{

FILE * infile=fopen("output.txt", "r");
if(infile==NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file");
    exit(1);
}

FileData **input;
int i=0;
while( fscanf(infile,"%d %f %[^\n]s",&input[i].a,&input[i].b,&input[i].dataStr)!  =NULL)
{
    printf("%d",input[i].a);
    printf("%.3f",input[i].b);
    printf("%[^\n]s",input[i].dataStr);
    i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

### My text file is

```
47
34.278
This is a line of text

48
23.678
This a very very long line

49
12.4569
This a very short line

50
117.906
This world is so beautiful

51
34.789
Hello world!
```

Comment: You never initialize `input`

Comment: Not an answer, but why `printf("%[^\n]s"...` instead of plain `printf("%s"...`

Comment: why did you declare input as pointer to pointer of FileData?

Comment: Here `FileData **input;` you need to allocate memory to `input` using malloc before using fscanf.

Comment: Why you reading till `\n`? If it is a valid string, then it should be terminated with `\0`. So simply use `fscanf("%s", someString);`, the same goes for `printf` too. Moreover, it seems, that the `FileData` should be of type `*input/just input`(IMHO) instead of `**input`, which you failed to initialize anyway(as already stated).

Comment: The `s` in `"%d %f %[^\n]s"` serves no purpose - it is not needed for %[].  Suggest dropping it.  `"%[^\n]"` has unbound width, should use `"%55[^\n]" - a width 1 less than the buffer size.

Comment: @nIcE cOw `fscanf(infile, "%s", someString);` will not scan "This is a line of text", but only "This".

Comment: @chux: Ahha good point. Thankx for reminding me. That is why I mostly comment in C language. Just new to it, still learning and sometimes forgetting minute thingies(as `%s` will read till first space). This one is one such thingy :-)

Comment: How would you have debugged the code shown using gdb, as it doesn't even compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you have a pointer:

```
FileData** input;
```

You are using that pointer even though it's not been initialized to point to any valid memory.

Since you are writing the data out to `stdout` immediately after reading from the file, you can use:

```
FileData input;
while( fscanf(infile,"%d %lf %55[^\n]",&input.a, &input.b, input.dataStr) == 3)
                                                                      // Notice the chage here
{
    printf("%d",input.a);
    printf("%.3f",input.b);
    printf("%s\n",input.dataStr);
}
```

But then, I don't understand the need for `struct _FileData`. You can just as easily use:

```
int intValue;
double doubleValue;
char stringValue[56];
while( fscanf(infile,"%d %lf %55[^\n]",&intValue, &doubleValue, stringValue) == 3)
{
    printf("%d %.3f %s\n",intValue, doubleValue, stringValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The struct _FileData is a part of assignment. I am unable to change it.

Comment: @SunnyTrinh are you getting the correct float values. I am getting all float values as 0.000 here.

Comment: Seems like we need to use %lf in fscanf function to work it properly.

Comment: @Sarwan Suggest removing `s` from `"%d %f %[^\n]s"`.  --> `"%d%lf %55[^\n]"`.

Comment: I have changed %f into %lf. It works perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: Better do `%55[^\n]` to make sure `datastr` could not get overflowed.