# Read text file and display content in ascii format

Tags: c, arrays, ascii, maze

I'm trying to read a maze file and convert to ascii and display when the code is run. i just cant seem to get it. How can i read and display the file. thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define height 8
#define width 12
#define WALL 219
#define SPACE ' '

//symbols
// where a space - a clear space in the maze
// 1 - a wall
// 2 - the entrance door(starting point)
// 3 - exit door
// 4 - internal destination point(end point)
// 5 - a way point

void displaymaze(int i, int j);
char maze[height][width];
int i, j;

int
main()
{
    FILE *myFile;

    myFile = fopen("example1.txt", "r");
    fclose(myFile);

    displaymaze(i, j);
    return (0);
}

void
displaymaze(int i, int j)
{

    printf("MAZE:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (maze[i][j] == '1') {
                maze[i][j] = WALL;
            }
            else if (maze[i][j] == ' ') {
                maze[i][j] = SPACE;
            }
            else if (maze[i][j] == '2') {
                maze[i][j] = ('S');
            }
            else if (maze[i][j] == '3')
                maze[i][j] = ('E');
            printf("%c", maze[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 things: **(1)** Condense this into a [mcve], or as close as you can get. **(2)** Explain what's going wrong. Don't just say "it doesn't work"; explain why you think that's the case. Note my choice to say "why **you think**" -- explain your thought process, too.

Comment: Hello I'm new to c. I expect the code to read the content of the file and print as in ascii

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't just post comments. Again, **include a [mcve]**, as well as **what's wrong** -- be detailed. We can't read your mind, and it's hard to read incorrect code and get an idea of what's supposed to be happening?

Comment: Ok thankyou I'll do so

Comment: So, you want to read a file which you already opened. I would suggest doing a google search to see how file system works in `C`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read ASCII code file using fscanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749729/read-ascii-code-file-using-fscanf)